# Using XMLHttpRequest Timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

So I am trying to use the timeout property of XMLHttpRequest to "recover" my program when a request for data times out. Basically if it fails in retrieving the data, I want it to try again. At the moment my code looks like this (full URL removed to fit it all neatly):

```
    function pullRequest(){

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                jsonDecode = this.responseText;
                json = JSON.parse(jsonDecode);
                ask = (json.result.Ask);
                bid = (json.result.Bid);
            }
        }

        xhr.open("GET","<URL>",true);
        xhr.send(); 
}
```

I'm not totally following how to implement the timeout property, or if it is even going to do what I want. I did add the following two lines after `xhr.open`but it threw and error:

```
        xhr.timeout = 5000;
        xhr.ontimeout = pullRequest()
```

Basically in my head if it times out, run the `pullRequest` function again. I'm sure this is probably not a good idea but I'm not experienced enough to know why. For what it's worth a snippet of the error is as follows:

```
...\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:165
    settings = {
    ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at exports.XMLHttpRequest.open
```

Any suggestions in how to achieve my goal, or a point to some literature that would assist me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I also recommend using `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {` instead of just `this.readyState === 4` because that one only checks if its finished, and not if it succeeded.

Comment: A couple of side-comments: 1. Either do use `;`, or don't use them and rely on Automatic Semicolon Insertion; don't mix-and-match. :-) 2. The `()` in `ask = (json.result.Ask);` serve no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah the code I've written is a mix and match of many started, stopped, and restarted versions mashed together. As I've learnt I done things more correctly but as you're seeing old code with "incorrect" formatting remains. I'll have to go through and clean it all up! FWIW I usually do use ";". Also in my defense my brother wrote the json.result lines and he knows even less about coding than I do :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're **calling** `pullRequest`:

```
xhr.ontimeout = pullRequest()
// ------------------------^^
```

Since it immediately calls itself, then calls itself again, and calls itself again, etc., eventually it runs out of stack when the maximum recursion level of the environment is reached.

You don't want to *call* it there, you just want to assign the function reference to `ontimeout` so that *if* the timeout occurs, your function gets called:

```
xhr.ontimeout = pullRequest
// No () ------------------^
```

Comment: Simple fix! I was suspecting something like that was happening but my limited knowledge meant I couldn't see what the problem was. I'll test it out although I have to leave my code running for sometimes days to get a time out as the API I am calling is pretty robust.